# ASP.Net Web API POST always returns 500- Internal Server Error on the server

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-7, http-post

The api is hosted on IIS. All the GET requests works fine,  but none of the POST requests are working. It always throw -> 500 Internal Server Error, with no more exception details.

Looked at the Handler mappings in iis, the setting has accept all verbs.Checked web.config seeting and it has -

```
<handlers>
<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
<remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

No errors are logged in event log or in -netpub\logs\LogFiles ..

This is the first time we added POST calls, earlier the api was handling only the GET calls.

What else do you think i could be missing?

Thanks,
WH

Comment: Please have a look at the event log. Usually 500 errors appear there...

Comment: Thanks @StephenReindl- errors are not logged in it either

Comment: have you tried putting a breakpoint at the top of the post method in visual studio and launching your project in debug ?  Does it hit the breakpoint?

Comment: can you post some code examples of a post method you are seeing working in Visual Studio but not on your server?  Tip: "Poster" plugin for Firefox is great for testing post requests in Web API.

Comment: did u find a solution for this?